# How to get platform information programatically in c/c++?

Tags: unix, operating-system

Is there any system call in unix to get the os name? How do we call "uname" programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uname()` is also a library function: [man 3 uname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uname)

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname name;

int result = uname(&name);
if (result == 0)
    printf("OS: %s\n", name.sysname);
```